# Weblogic server consuming message more than once

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

Using Weblogic server JMS with MDB as Message listener is receiving message for 3 times.

This is my Consumer code :

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/myQueue", activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class JMSMessageConsumer implements MessageListener {

    public JMSMessageConsumer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if(message instanceof TextMessage){
            try {
                System.out.println("Message Id >> "+message.getJMSMessageID());
                String mess = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
                message.acknowledge();
                System.out.println("Message Received"+mess);
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to in server check how many message are sending to queue and receiving from queue?

Strictly I need send and receive one-to-one (P-to-P) message , please suggest how I can check and configure in WLS.

Comment: Hi. It should work. I tested on my side on weblogic12.2.1.2 and the message is consumed only once. Do you have additionnal configuration? (weblogic-ejb-jar.xml? ). On which version of weblogic12C are you running?

Comment: Also, your problem could come from the producer. Are you sure your message is sent only once?

Comment: Yes I am sending only once where I am using 12.1.2 version.Please suggest Is it possible to check in Weblogic server for producer and consumer message count.

Comment: I found same message Id is getting listened again and again in my consumer. If I test the application from same it listening only once but I am sending message from different application and consumer is a different application. Is there any way to avoid listening same message Id again and again

Comment: Can you try removing the `message.acknowledge()` instruction? In a MDB, messages are handled by the container so by default, if there are not any error in your `onMessage` method, message is removed from queue.